# Display geographic coordinates in a projected OpenLayers map

Tags: openlayers, coordinates

I'm using OpenLayers 6 to create a projected map in EPSG:25830. I've included the following code to display the coordinates in the map and it works ok

```
controls: ol.control.defaults().extend ([
            new ol.control.MousePosition ({
                coordinateFormat: ol.coordinate.createStringXY(2),
            }),
```

[image]

Now I would like to know how to display the geographic coordinates instead of the projected ones. I've come across the function `useGeographic` that seems to do what I need but I wouldn't know how to use it.

Comment: If you are happy with a display in Lon Lat order you simply need to specify EPSG:4326 in the MousePosition options as in this exampk https://codesandbox.io/s/simple-forked-tt6wt7?file=/main.js (where the view is EPSG:32635

Comment: It definitely does whay I want. If you put it as an answer, I can validate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are happy with a display in Lon Lat order you simply need to specify EPSG:4326 in the MousePosition options:

```
controls: ol.control.defaults().extend ([
            new ol.control.MousePosition ({
                coordinateFormat: ol.coordinate.createStringXY(2),
                projection: 'EPSG:4326',
            }),
```